# When opening read only excel file save as dialog box is displayed

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, read-only

When I open read only excel file save as dialog box opens and I can't read file without saving a copy of it.Also a new excel file created in desktop can't saves the modification . Every time save as box appears if i try to save.

I have full permission for  read,write and modification. The excel files created in desktop  are not saved in read-only mode.I am using Excel 2007 and this error occurs only for one user.

Opening excel files in safe mode solves error. But is there any other method to solve this error?

Comment: Does that user have the correct permissions set up for the location where the files are stored? From what you are saying I suspect not.

Comment: As @Mokubai told, I too suspect this has something to do with the permissions for that user.